# Is there any way to use require and import in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two differents files in a node project, in one of them, I have to use a json file to extract an array, I was using require. In the other one, I have to import some features from a module.
The problem is, importing is not working if I don't have

```
"type" : "module"
```

In my package.json, but doing this, require is not working.
I tried to change require for import with the json file, but to execute, I have to use

```
node --experimental-json-modules file.js
```

And we are suppose not to use that flag when running.

Comment: the json file is just contaning an array with some objects, but if just run "node file.js" with the json imported, the error was about the .json extension

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question; you've already tried that. You should be able to just use require for everything though.

Comment: But I can't, when I add "type": "module" in package.json, require just dont work

Comment: The don't; don't use `import` and don't add `"type": "module"`

Comment: I need it to import the features from a module in other file

Comment: In that case the only alternative is to load the JSON file from disk using `fs` and parse it.

Comment: What Chris G said: the other option is "don’t use `require`". (`--experimental-json-modules` is a thing, but while it’s experimental, `fs` is better.)

Answer (score 0):

You should pick `require()` or `import` - not both.  When in an ESM module (where you can use `import`), `require()` is not defined.  If you want to use `import` for loading modules, then set up the `"type": "module"` properly and use `import`.  Then, to load a JSON file, all it takes is a little function:

```
async function loadJSON(file) {
    let data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Or, if you want to do it synchronously:

```
function loadJSONSync(file)  {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Which you can put into a shared module itself so you can use it anywhere you want.  Note that in both of these functions, you will need to catch errors.  With the asynchronous option, it returns a promise and you need to check for both success and rejection.  For the synchronous version, you need to catch any exceptions it might throw.